# What is the Jython or Python equivalent of the following VBScript?

Tags: python, vbscript, jython-2.7

What do the below lines of code do? And what is its Jython equivalent?

```vb
Function Import_PUERTOR(strField, strRecord)
    Dim re 
    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "^\s*"
    re.MultiLine = False
    strField = re.Replace(strField,"")
End Function
```

Comment: Format your question properly so we can read the code, and make your actual question clearer so we understand what you want.

Answer (score 4):

this code strips the leading spaces from the left of the `strField` string.

Python regex conversion? no need, python has a non-regex built-in for that (faster, shorter to write):

```
strField  = strField.lstrip()
```

will do

> `lstrip` returns a copy of the string with leading characters removed.
>   Syntax
>   str. lstrip([chars])
>
> chars
>      Optional. String specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace. The chars argument is not a prefix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped.